# Итерирование по односвязному списку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Писал класс односвязного списка:

```
class ListNode:
  def __init__(self, v, nxt):
    self._value = v
    self._next = nxt

  def __repr__(self):
    return 'ListNode: Value: {0}, Next: {1}'.format(self._value, self._next)

  def __str__(self):
    return '({0}, {1})'.format(self._value, self._next)

  def getValue(self):
      return self._value

  def setValue(self, v):
      self._value = v

  def getNext(self):
      return self._next

  def setNext(self, v):
      self._next = v

  value = property(getValue, setValue)
  next = property(getNext, setNext)



class ListNode2(ListNode):
  def __init__(self, v, nxt, prev):
    ListNode.__init__(self, v, nxt)
    self._previous = prev

  def __repr__(self):
    return 'ListNode: Value: {0}, Next: {1}, Previous: {2}'.format(self._value, self._next, self._previous)

  def __str__(self):
    return '({0}, {1}, {2})'.format(self._value, self._next, self._previous)

  def getPrevious(self):
      return self._previous

  def setPrevious(self, v):
      self._previous = v

  previous = property(getPrevious, setPrevious)



class LinkedList:
  def __init__(self):
    self._head = None

  def getHead(self):
      return self._head

  head = property(getHead)

  def Add(self, node):
    node.next = self._head
    self._head = node

  def Remove(self):
    if self._head != None:
      self._head = self._head.next

  def __iter__(self):
      return self

  def next(self):
    current = self._head
    while current != None:
      yield current.Value
      current = current.next

l = LinkedList()
for i in range(10):
  l.Add(ListNode(i, None))

for data in l: # Надо, сделать так, чтобы так можно было перебирать весь список.
  print(data)
```

Comment: Вопрос-то в чём?

Comment: Как сделать возможность итерирования по списку класса LinkedList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы, судя по несоблюдению PEP8 и лишним телодвижениям, в Python пришли из Java? Прежде всего, вам не нужен посредник в виде класса `LinkedList`. Узлы сами способны отвечать за своё состояние и представлять связанный список. Что касается непосредственно итерирования, есть два способа - с явным итератором и с генератором.

Первый вариант:

```
class LinkedListIterator:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self._item = item

    __iter__ = lambda self: self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._item is None:
            raise StopIteration
        item, self._item = self._item, self._item.next
        return item


class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def __add__(self, value):
        self.next = Node(value)
        return self.next

    def __iter__(self):
        return LinkedListIterator(self)
```

Второй вариант:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def __add__(self, value):
        self.next = Node(value)
        return self.next

    def __iter__(self):
        item = self
        while item is not None:
            yield item
            item = item.next
```

И пример использования:

```
head = Node(1)
tail = head + 2
tail += 3
tail += 4
tail += 5

for i in head:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Из C# перешел...

Comment: Я почти угадал :)

Comment: 1. "Прежде всего, вам не нужен посредник в виде класса LinkedList." Но почему в C# это нужно, а тут нет? В C# узлы по сути также могли это делать, но там же предпочли реализацию списка через некоторый класс, который управляет самими узлами списка.

2. Почему Вы отказались от использования property?

Comment: 1. В языках типа Java и C# использование многослойных абстракций - это норма, но для Python это не идиоматично. 2. Прямая работа с полями, если не требуется дополнительная логика - это тоже _python way_.

Comment: Хм, хорошо. Буду исправляться на python way :).

Comment: Кстати, если мне посредник не нужен (класс LinkedList), то как реализовать удаление первого узла из списка?

Comment: @VladislavMoldovan не нужно исправляться. не впадайте в крайность.

Comment: Я в плане написания кода на Python. А не в плане написания кода вообще.

Comment: @VladislavMoldovan легко `head, head.next = head.next, None`

Comment: @VladislavMoldovan Излишек абстракций -плохо, недостаток - ничуть не лучше. Заменить LinkedList на Node - второй случай. Выбросив его ради " python way" вы ничего не выиграете, только добавите себе головняка

Comment: добавьте в итератор: `__iter__ = lambda self: self`. В сторону: в чистом Питоне применение явных односвязных списков это скорее всего ошибка (менее читаемый, менее эффективный код).